# Serving static files not working properly in express server after domain name integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl, lets-encrypt

I want to access my static files directly with express server.
Folder structure:

`\app 
    \.well-known
        \acme-challenge
            file1
    server.js`

In server.js I have written following code:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname, { dotfiles: 'allow' }));`

This works for my local and production server and when I am hitting

For local: `http://localhost:8080/.well-known/acme-challenge/file1`

For prod: `http://server_IP:8080/.well-known/acme-challenge/file1`

With above url I can directly download the file.

But same thing if I am trying to access using domain name I am getting following html in response

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
        <meta name="KEYWORDS" content="">
        <meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="">
        <meta name="VERSION" content="">
        <link href="" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows='100%, *' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
        <frame src="http://server_IP:8080" name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></frame>
    </frameset>
    <noframes>
        <h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your browser.</h2><br><br>
        <center>Click <a href="http://server_IP:8080" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
    </noframes>
</html>
```

It's hosted on linode dedicated machine.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you hosting?

Comment: This has nothing to do with node or express, your hosting provider is sticking your website in an iFrame,..  Is there some setting with `linode` you need to change.

Comment: But it works when I am using server ip and port 
http://server_IP:8080/.well-known/acme-challenge/file1
It fails only when I am replacing `server_IP:8080` with `domain_name`

Comment: That's because whatever your using for your `domain_name` is wrapping your website inside an iframe,.. IOW: Your Domain name's A record is not pointing at your server.  So it's your Domain name service provider who's doing this.  Who's your Domain with?  To test this try -> `ping yournamename` your will find it's not pointing at your server, but your Domain suppliers.   Your using a simple website wrapping domain name service, you want your Domain names A record changing instead.

Comment: https://ap.www.namecheap.com

Comment: Go into your namescheap control panel, and alter the mode it's using,.. Setup an `A record` to point at your websites IP address, and you will be good to go.

Comment: I have multiple websites running on different port numbers but in `A record` configuration I can add only IP. How I can map the port ?